# The getter "some variable" isn't defined for the type 'Rx<some class>' while using getx controller

Tags: flutter, getter, flutter-getx

I am trying to implement **reactive getx** for my project to achieve cleaner code.

In the controller dart file, I have:

```
class ReadSinglePostController extends GetxController {
  var posts = Post(
          postID: 1,
          userID: 0,
          thumbnail: 'some base64string',
          imageList: 'some base64string',
          title: 'title',
          description: 'description',
          createdTime: DateTime.now())
      .obs;//initialization and make the class Post observable
  var postid = 0.obs; //initialize postid and make it observable
  void updateID(var postID) {
    postid = postID;
  } //update the postid variable when a specific post is clicked in the post list

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    readPost(postid);
  }

  Future readPost(var postID) async {
    var result = await PostsDatabase.instance.readNote(postID);
    posts = result;
  }//function to read the detailed content of that specific post from database passing in the postid
}
```

Then on the homepage of the UI, where I have all posts in a grid, I implement this controller to update the `postid` when a specific post is clicked. When a post is clicked, it navigates into the post detail page, and in that UI file, the **error** comes in:

`Error:The getter "thumbnail" isn't defined for the type 'Rx<Post>'.` **and the same error comes up when I use getter 'title', 'description' and etc.**

Here is the code:

```
class PostBody extends StatelessWidget {
  PostBody({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final readSinglePostController = Get.put(ReadSinglePostController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: GetX<ReadSinglePostController>(
                builder: (controller) {
                  return ...
                              ...
                                ...
                                child: FadeInImage(
                                  placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                                  image:
                                      Utility.imageFromBase64String(
                                              controller.posts.thumbnail)//Error:The getter "thumbnail" isn't defined for the type 'Rx<Post>'. and the same error comes up when I use getter 'title', 'description' and etc.
                                          .image,
                                ),...
```

Any clue, guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN Getx, `Rx<T>` is a wrapper on `T`.

Which means when you call `controller.posts` you are getting an instance of the reactive type that is `Rx<Post>`.

Now, `Rx<Post>` wouldn't directly know what members are present inside of `Post` and that is why you are unable to access them directly.

Instead you must first obtain the `value` from the reactive object which gives you the actual `Post` instance that the `Rx` is wrapping. From that you can access your instance variables.

```
controller.posts.value.thumbnail
```

Here, `controller.posts.value` is of type `Post`.

Comment: Dear Nisanth, Thank you for your answer. I changed to `controller.posts.value`, but now it gives me another error: `[Get] the improper use of a GetX or Obx for the  specific widget that will be updated.   If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable). If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX` Basically, It's saying the observer can't update?

Comment: I'm confused that after I hot reloaded, the error was gone. But if I build it again with flutter run, then the same getx error still pops up...

Comment: This is happening because your widget structure is a bit misshpen. You are using `child: GetX<ReadSinglePostController>(` but inside the builder, you have a looot of widget that don't depend on the `obs`. So your builder method of `GetX<>()` should be as small as possible. Move all the wigets that dont depend on the `obs` outside of the builder and this will be resolved. The error text is saying that you basically have to remove the `HeavyWidget` from inside your `GetX` and just have `GetX => variableObservable`